# Compile error: "Variable Trigger does not exist" in a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Just want to know what am I missing here.

```
trigger updateLastCallDate on Task (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> con_set = new Set<Id>();

    List<Contact> con_list = new List<Contact>();

    for(Task T: Trigger.new()){
        if(String.valueof(T.WhatId).startsWith('001') &&
            T.Status=='Completed' && T.Subject=='Call' ) {
            con_set.add(T.WhatId);
        }
     }

     for (AggregateResult aggregateResult: [SELECT max(createdDate)MaxCDate, WhatId
        FROM Task WHERE WhatID IN: con_set AND Status ='Completed'
        AND Subject ='Call' Group By WhatId]) {
        con_list.add(new Contact(Id=(id)aggregateResult.get('WhatId'),Last_Call__c=date.valueof(aggregateResult.get('MaxCDate'))));
     }

     try {
         if(con_list !=null && con_list.size()>0) {
             update con_list;
         }
     } catch(Exception e) {
         system.debug('Exception ***'+e.getMessage());
     }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Are you receiving an error?  If so, can you include it in your question?

Comment: one mistake i noticed you are adding AccountId in `con_set` this set and below assigning AccountId to contact `Contact(Id=(id)aggregateResult.get('WhatId')`.... Except this code look good to me. pls specify line no where you are getting eror

Answer (score 7):

The compile error is because you have this:

```
for(Task T: Trigger.new()){
```

so the compiler thinks `.new()` is a method on a variable named `Trigger`, when it's actually a [system context variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm). It should be:

```
for (Task t : trigger.new) {
```

Comment: Nice one.  It's only now that you've posted this that the question makes sense.

Comment: ohh yes this is the mistake.

Comment: Thansk for the comments guys but...
It's giving me an error...
Trigger name exists on different SObject type: Contact

If I change Task to contact then I have to change all "Task" then it gives me an error that WHATID doesnt exist.  Isnt the sObject has to be on contact?

Comment: That error means that you already have a trigger on Contact named the same thing...rename this one to resolve it. If this answer answered your question and if you have a different question, please create a new post :)

Comment: I actually dont. :( I renamed a couple of times and the same error